# How to translate "warcraft" in French?

Tags: traduction

I'm a French native speaker, and I've looked for some time how to translate the word **warcraft** into French.

The web is polluted with references to the game or the universe. So I can't really find something satisfying.

Warcraft is composed, obviously, of the word **war** and **craft**, the former meaning **guerre** and the latter meaning **art** or **métier**.

The only place I've seen that term used is to refer to a warship in the recent movie **Infinity War**. In the first minutes, they refer to their ship, saying **this is not a warcraft** (i.e. not a warship)

My question is then the following : **how do you translate warcraft?** be it with one or more words.

Comment: Maybe "l'effort de guerre".

Comment: _warcraft_ dans le sens de _navire de guerre_ est à rapprocher de _aircraft_ et _spacecraft_.

Comment: "warcraft" does not exist; the term to use is "warship".

Comment: Yes, this question with the example it gives is odd. “Warcraft” cannot be used to refer to a ship and native speakers would find that confusing. Warcraft is “the art of war.” So it’s really a very odd example you give since by your own explanation you know it doesn’t mean that.

Answer (score 9):

Warcraft se traduirait la plupart du temps (vu l'engouement du jeu vidéo qui a rendu ce mot célèbre) par:

```
l'art de la guerre
```

Cependant, dans le contexte de la question, il prend une autre signification :

```
Navire de guerre
```

En effet, le mot "craft" tout seul peut se traduire par "artisanat" ou par "bateau" (en particulier, "landing craft" désigne les [péniches de débarquement](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=landing%20craft%20&t=ffab&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images)). Il me semble donc logique que l'on parle de la seconde traduction vu que "ship" est également un bateau.

Comment: Pourquoi navire de guerre et art de la guerre  (et pas de guerre) ?

Comment: bonne question, je n'y avais pas pensé tellement cela me semble naturel mais je ne sais pas ce qu'il en est. Mon hypothèse est que l'art de la guerre = comment bien faire une guerre (cfr livre du même nom, de Sun Tzu), alors que si l'on parlait d'art de guerre, cela toucherait à une forme d'art (peinture, sculpture...) dans le contexte d'une guerre (par exemple, des obus sculptés comme on peut en voir au musée de la Somme

Comment: Merci bien. Une autre question serait pourquoi les tournures françaises sont (il me paraît) plus grandes que celles de l'anglais. Mais je pense c'est une grande question pour répondre ici☺.

Comment: l'ouvrage de Sun Tzu serait plutôt "Art of War" en anglais (cf wikipedia). "craft" c'est plutôt "artisanat", mais "l'artisanat de la guerre" ça le fait pas (une guerre artisanale à la limite, mais on s'éloigne de warcraft).

Comment: Pour moi, "art of war" est le sens qu'ont voulu donner les créateurs du jeu vidéo, et une traduction inverse rigoureuse ne devrait pas mener à une utilisation de warcraft en anglais (qui n'est pas dans le dictionnaire).  Il y a toutefois un livre qui s'appelle "QI MEN DUN JIA SUN TZU WARCRAFT"

Comment: Dimitris, les tournures françaises ne sont pas plus **grandes** que leur équivalent anglais, elles sont en revanche souvent plus **longues** ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre Merci.  Longues et pas grandes ☺! Quelle naïveté.

Comment: Dimitris: pour te répondre, j'avais demandé à un écrivain cette exacte même question (qui mériterait un post à part entière)  il m'a répondu que le français était long et précis parce que c'est une langue taillée pour faire des discours et occuper l'espace oratoire.Il circule aussi une théorie évoquant que la langue est ainsi (avec des fromules longues et des informations dans les mots rendant prédctibles leur contexte) c'est par design, de sorte à ce que si des morceaux de phrases écrites se perdent on puisse retrouver plus facilement le reste des messages.

Answer (score 2):

According to livio (Android dictionary) warcraft has two significations. For the game I think it is the first one which is appropriate. On the other hand, regarding the ship (2) is the proper translation.

> 1) The art or skill of conducting a war. => L'art ou la compétence de mener une guerre.
>
> 2) Warship => navire de guerre.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/warcraft